# Avoid autosearch

Tags: jquery, html, backbone.js

I recently implemented Christophe Coenraets' Employee Directory App to our company, simplifying it a bit, since we don't need manager functionality.

One thing that is keeping me from release, is the autosearch feature, that I simply can't find a way of deactivating it, and instead set up a standard search box and submit button behavior. Our 1500+ employee database is too much for even the iPhone 5, and is very slow and sluggish.

I tried posting on his blog, but it gives me a database error.

Here is the link to his App: http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/03/employee-directory-sample-app-with-backbone-js-and-jquery-mobile/

Anyone familiar with this App or backbone.js that might throw some light on this?

Many thanks.

**UPDATE**: I found an easier way of implementing the search by delaying it 1.5 seconds. I added the _.debounce function of the underscore.js framework here:

```
search: _.debounce(function(event){
var key = $('.search-key').val();
this.model.findByName(key);
}, 1500)
});
```

Thanks again for your responses.

**UPDATE 2**: I went and tried to make the App work with the enter key, instead of the wait period. This is my code so far, but it just stays there, and doesn't respond to the Enter key. The console says nothing either. Any ideas?

```
events: {
    //"keyup .search-query": "search",
    "keypress .search-query": "onkeypress"
},

search: function () {
    var key = $('.search-key').val();
    console.log('search ' + key);
    this.searchResults.findByName(key);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.dropdown').addClass('open');
    });
},

onkeypress: function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.search()
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My initial glance at that application shows that the search feature does a HTTP request to get a JSON array of employee data that fills that dropdown after keystrokes.

This should be as simple as restricting the number of results that backend code returns to a reasonable number.

If you wanted to be more user friendly - display the # of records returned, out of # records found - and instruct them to be more specific in their search to narrow down the resultset.

Answer (score 0):

It's there:
https://github.com/ccoenraets/backbone-directory/blob/master/web/js/views/header.js#L15

You need to change it to something like this:

```
events: {
    //"keyup .search-query": "search",
    "keypress .search-query": "onkeypress"
},

search: function () {
    var key = $('#searchText').val();
    console.log('search ' + key);
    this.searchResults.findByName(key);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('.dropdown').addClass('open');
    });
},

onkeypress: function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.search()
    }
},
```

This will turn off the auto search and to initiate the search, the user will have to press enter.

Like thinice I would also suggest limiting the number of results. Add some pagination maybe?
In case you want to go for pagination, look here: https://github.com/ccoenraets/backbone-directory/blob/master/api/index.php#L15

Comment: I already release the App with the search delay, but I began modifying it for keypress event instead of keyup.
So far I've been unable to get it to work.

I'll post the modified code as an Update in the main question.

Thanks again.